# Is the cosine similarity of sums of vector pairs equal to the sum of the cosine similarities of the vector pairs?

Tags: linear-algebra

Assuming I have two vectors x and y that are the sum of two vectors:
x = x_a + x_b
y = y_a + y_b

and a similarity measure (cosine similarity)
s(x,y) = x dot y / (norm(x)*norm(y))

Could anybody help me determining whether the following holds

s(x_a + x_b, y_a + y_b) = s(x_a, y_a) + s(x_b, y_b)

I tried to work it out on paper and got stuck - I assume I'm missing some trick for rearranging the equations.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Michael

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: for some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238).

Answer (score 1):

No, this doesn't hold. A simple counterexample is afforded by $x_a\perp y_a$ and $x_b=y_a$ and $y_b=x_a$; in this case the left-hand side is $1$ whereas the right-hand side is $0$.

Comment: thank you for the quick response